# MiniZinc: build a connectivity matrix

Tags: minizinc

In MiniZinc, I have an array of boolean representing an oriented connection between nodes of a graph:

```
array[Variants,Variants] of bool : VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf;
```

VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf[v1,v2] = true if there is an oriented arc "v1 -> v2".

now I want to build
array[Variants,Variants] of bool VariantIsUpwardOf;
where VariantIsUpwardOf[v1,v2] = true if there is an oriented path "v1 -> ... -> v2" where "..." is a sequence of nodes defining an oriented path of any length going from v1 to v2.

My first try was to define a transitive kind of constraint

```
array[Variants,Variants] of var bool : VariantIsUpwardOf;
constraint forall (v1 in Variants, v2 in Variants)(VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf[v1,v2]->VariantIsUpwardOf[v1,v2]);
constraint forall (v1 in Variants, v2 in Variants, v3 in Variants)( VariantIsUpwardOf[v1,v2] /\ VariantIsUpwardOf[v2,v3] -> VariantIsUpwardOf[v1,v3]);
```

but I think this is incorrect because if all values of VariantIsUpwardOf[v1,v2] were true, then my constraints would be satisfied and the result would be incorrect.

Following the comment (thanks Axel), I made a second unsuccessful test using predicate dpath, here is my very basic test calling dpath::

```
include "path.mzn";

enum MyNodes={N1,N2};
array [int] of MyNodes: EdgeFrom=[N1];
array [int] of MyNodes: EdgeTo=  [N2];

array [MyNodes] of bool: NodesInSubGraph = [true, true];
array [int] of bool: EdgesInSubGraph = [true];

var bool : MyTest = dpath(EdgeFrom,EdgeTo,N1,N2,NodesInSubGraph,EdgesInSubGraph); 
output [show(MyTest)];
```

it produces the following error:

```
Running MiniTest.mzn
221msec

fzn_dpath_enum_reif:3.3-52
  in call 'abort'
MiniZinc: evaluation error: Abort: Reified dpath constraint is not supported
Process finished with non-zero exit code 1.
Finished in 221msec.
```

Comment: Have a look at [MiniZinc Graph Constraints](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-globals-graph.html).

Comment: thanks Axel, I tried this and documented my failure in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following MiniZinc model demonstrates the usage of the [dpath()](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-globals-graph.html) predicate to find a directed path in a graph.

I took the directed graph from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) as example:

[image]

**The model:**

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: Nodes = 4;
bool: T = true;   %  abbreviate typing
bool: F = false;
set of int: Variants = 1..Nodes;

%  VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf[v1,v2] = true if there is an oriented arc "v1 -> v2".
%  Example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph
array[Variants,Variants] of bool : VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf =
  [| F, T, T, F,
   | F, F, F, F,
   | F, T, F, T,
   | F, F, T, F |];
   
%  count the number of Edges as 2D array sum
int: NoOfEdges = sum(VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf);
set of int: Edges = 1..NoOfEdges;

%  for dpath(), the graph has to be represented as two
%  'from' 'to' arrays of Nodes
%  cf. https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-globals-graph.html
array[Edges] of Variants: fromNodes = 
  [row | row in Variants, col in Variants 
   where VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf[row, col]];
array[Edges] of Variants: toNodes = 
  [col | row in Variants, col in Variants 
   where VariantIsDirectlyUpwardOf[row, col]];

%  arbitrary choice of Nodes to be connected by a directed path
Variants: sourceNode = 4;
Variants: destNode = 2;

%  decision variables as result of the path search
array[Variants] of var bool: nodesInPath;
array[Edges] of var bool: edgesInPath;
   
constraint dpath(fromNodes, toNodes, sourceNode, destNode, nodesInPath, edgesInPath);

%  determine next node after nd in path
function int: successor(int: nd) =
  min([s | s in Variants, e in Edges where 
      fix(nodesInPath[s]) /\ fix(edgesInPath[e]) /\ 
      (fromNodes[e] = nd) /\ (toNodes[e] = s)]);

function string: showPath(int: nd) =
  if nd = destNode then "\(nd)" else "\(nd)->" ++ showPath(successor(nd)) endif;

output [showPath(sourceNode)];
```

**Resulting output:**

```
4->3->2
```